# T-SQL : return latest value of each ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, distinct

I have a table looks like

```
ID, name, Likes, Login_time
```

`select * from mytbl`

[image]

I want to filter this table:

```
distinct ID, name like, login_time(last login time)
```

[image]

I tried this query, but it didn't work.

```
select * 
from
    (select 
         name, likes, login_time
         rank() over (partition by id order by login_time desc) as rank
     from 
         mytbl) t
where 
    t.rank = 1
```

Comment: I think you might want to use `ROW_NUMBER()` here rather than `RANK()`, but that aside, what isn't working?  Your query should give you the result set you want, I think.

Comment: What are you expecting `2017-03-31 03:53:39.000` as the latest login time for `name1`?  Based on your sample data, `2017-03-31 04:33:15.000` is the most recent entry.

Comment: Thats just for sample, I have manually typed in Excel.

Comment: Show us the current output, and explain why you think that output is wrong.  I don't see a problem with your query.

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near '('.

Comment: Oh dear, you're missing a comma after `login_time` in your `SELECT` statement.  Do you see that?

Comment: Does this help, check i tried something. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e6e61/4

Comment: oh yes, i missed comma :( , thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use row_number instead of rank

```
select * 
from
(
select 
        id, name, likes, login_time,
         ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by id order by login_time desc) as rank
     from 
         mytbl )t
where 
    t.rank = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 ;WITH temps AS
    (
   SELECT Id, name, likes, login_time, row_number() over(PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY login_time desc) AS RowIndex
  )
SELECT Id, name, likes, login_time FROM temps 
WHERE RowIndex = 1
```

Comment: Why would you expect this query to solve the OP's question?